# Addressing modes involving ESP?

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I was studying assembly and I would like some additional clarifications for the below code

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS: [ESP+16], 6E616C41
```

So basically where is it loading `6E616C41` to?

I've learned that stack grows in decreasing order in some architecture so if

```
ESP 006FFEF0
```

Is `6E616C41` moved to the location `006FFEF0 - 16 = 006FFEDA` ?

Comment: It's not loading it, it's *storing* it to memory, 16 bytes above the current stack pointer.  Note the +16, not -16.  And note that `16` is in decimal, not hex.

Comment: How's the address calculated?  006FFEF0 - 16?

Comment: No, `0x006FFEF0 + 16`, not `-`.  With both numbers in hex, `0x006FFEF0 + 0xa`.  The stack grows downward, but that just means that `push` decrements, `pop` increments.  Not that addressing modes work differently when ESP is involved.  IDK if that's why you were negating, instead of a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's clear now, thanks

Comment: @Peter Cordes: 16 decimal is 10h hex, not 0Ah.

Comment: @ecm: derp, thanks.  I think I was looking at the `...A` number in the question, and/or converted it to 0x10 in my head and then converted 10d -> 0xa as I was typing :/